# width: auto problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a checklist (which I guess would be similar to a single column List-View with the LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES extended style in Windows) using a div and inserting checkboxes in it with JS and associated label each on their own line. Each line would look like this

```
<label for="cb" style="white-space: nowrap;">Label<input type="checkbox" id="cb" /></label>
```

I've set the width of the div to be auto so it automatically resizes based on the content and made sure the labels don't wrap on white spaces but that cause the div width to be smaller than the content forcing a horizontal scroll bar to appear.

Here's an example of the HTML code produced by the JS as reported by Firebug:

```
<div class="employees_list_column">
<div id="employees" class="check_list_wx" style="height: 130px; width: auto;">
<label style="white-space: nowrap" for="checklistwx_employees_35">
<input id="checklistwx_employees_35" type="checkbox" name="checklistwx_employees_35">E*** I*****
</label>
<br/>
<label style="white-space: nowrap" for="checklistwx_employees_45">
<input id="checklistwx_employees_45" type="checkbox" name="checklistwx_employees_45">F*** P*****
</label>
<br/>
<label style="white-space: nowrap" for="checklistwx_employees_34">
<input id="checklistwx_employees_34" type="checkbox" name="checklistwx_employees_34">J******* C***
</label>
<br/>
<label style="white-space: nowrap" for="checklistwx_employees_37">
<input id="checklistwx_employees_37" type="checkbox" name="checklistwx_employees_37">J****** M*****
</label>
<br/>
<label style="white-space: nowrap" for="checklistwx_employees_1">
<input id="checklistwx_employees_1" type="checkbox" name="checklistwx_employees_1">L**** M***********
</label>
<br/>
<label style="white-space: nowrap" for="checklistwx_employees_2">
<input id="checklistwx_employees_2" type="checkbox" name="checklistwx_employees_2">M****** F*******
</label>
<br/>
<label style="white-space: nowrap" for="checklistwx_employees_3">
<input id="checklistwx_employees_3" type="checkbox" name="checklistwx_employees_3">N*** A*******
</label>
<br/>
<label style="white-space: nowrap" for="checklistwx_employees_4">
<input id="checklistwx_employees_4" type="checkbox" name="checklistwx_employees_4">O****** P*******
</label>
<br/>
<label style="white-space: nowrap" for="checklistwx_employees_5">
<input id="checklistwx_employees_5" type="checkbox" name="checklistwx_employees_5">P*** T******
</label>
<br/>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
element.style {
  height: 230px;
  width: auto;
}

  .check_list_wx {
  border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.employees_list_column {
  float: left;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

Any ideas why the width of my div is smaller than the content?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your CSS. `check_list_wx` is being treated as a DOM node type instead of a class reference because it is missing the preceding `.`. Since it never gets the `display:inline-block;` assignment, it continues to be treated as a block element and takes up the full width of the parent.

Change

```
check_list_wx {
  border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

to

```
.check_list_wx {
  border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/zMQey/

Comment: With all of those thousands of +1 that this answer has gotten. I feel i should inform that older versions of ie ( ie 6 & 7 ) will not like this. Though i do feel like giving plus just for the avatar... ;)

Comment: Dux my man! Yea ie6 will bail. IE7 should be ok. Besides, even M$ is ditching IE6 - http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: Well, netrenderer says ie 7 shows the width as 100% would show it basically. Yea i love that ms is ditching it plus.. I live in finland so at work i dont quite have to worry about ie6. Though, personally i stopped caring about it long ago.

Comment: My bad, missed the . when I copied from firebug.

Answer (score 1):

`width: auto;` does not mean that your `div` will automatically resize based on the content. It means that it automatically takes the width of its parent element. `width: auto;` is also the default width of a `div`.

Below is a simplified working sample. Notice the `overflow-x: hidden;` and `padding: 0 16px 0 0;` on the check box list. This makes sure that there will be no horizontal scrollbar and that no content will be hidden at the right edge.

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
    <title>Check box list with vertical scrollbar</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .checkBoxList
        {
            border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
            height: 130px;
            float: left;
            line-height: 24px;
            padding: 0 16px 0 0;
            overflow: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        .checkBoxList label
        {
            display: block;
            white-space: nowrap;
            letter-spacing: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head><body>
    <div class="checkBoxList">
        <label for="cb1"><input id="cb1" type="checkbox"/>Check box 1</label>
        <label for="cb2"><input id="cb2" type="checkbox"/>Check box 2</label>
        <label for="cb3"><input id="cb3" type="checkbox"/>Check box 3</label>
        <label for="cb4"><input id="cb4" type="checkbox"/>Check box 4</label>
        <label for="cb5"><input id="cb5" type="checkbox"/>Check box 5</label>
        <label for="cb6"><input id="cb6" type="checkbox"/>Check box 6</label>
        <label for="cb7"><input id="cb7" type="checkbox"/>Check box 7</label>
        <label for="cb8"><input id="cb8" type="checkbox"/>Check box 8</label>
        <label for="cb9"><input id="cb9" type="checkbox"/>Check box 9</label>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

You can find more information about the CSS overflow property here: http://css-tricks.com/2833-the-css-overflow-property/.

Comment: -1 for telling her she needs to increase her parent element width. +1 for explaining that `width:auto;` is being used incorrectly.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I removed the part about increasing the width of the parent. I also did your suggested CSS adjustment, but I can't see any problems. Do you get the scrollbar?

Comment: No scrollbar on my fiddle on Chrome at least.

Comment: Oopsie, didn't know that. What would the best way to automatically size an element based on it's content (without JS of course)? The answer below is suggesting using float: left but it feels a bit like a dirty fix to me since I'm going to have to clear it with another div after. :S

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is anymore, can you please clarify your question? I thought it was about getting rid of the scrollbar, but when I try your example I don't get any scrollbar.

Comment: Yes, I want to get rid of the hor. scrollbar. I just realised there wasn't enough elements in my example to cause scrollbars to appear. I've updated Lollero's fiddle with a new example that has more employees and reduced the height to force scrollbars. While doing this I realised the hor. scrollbar is scrolling for exactly the width of the ver. scrollbar. The div actually takes the width of the content but since the ver. scrollbar hides some of the content it forces a hor. scrollbar. What would be the best way to set the width to be content + hor. scrollbar. http://jsfiddle.net/hdxdw/

Comment: Oh, apparently changes I've made on fiddle are not actually saved. Updated example above.

Answer (score 0):

`float: left;` is the thing that you can use if you want the outer element to wrap around the content.

**Edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/hdxdw/

Comment: Is that the only solution? It feels like a dirty fix to me since I'm going to have to clear it with another div after.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why it would be dirty. Anyways i added example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example. There is a few things I don't understand though about it. I've play a bit with the code but I don't understand what setting both float: left and clear: both on the same div does. Also, in the CSS I see clear: both and the element has clear: none. To me it seems clear: both does nothing but I thought I'd ask in case this was some kind of trick.

Comment: In this case `float: left;` is not used to just float the object to the left, it's just a side effect. Float more or less establishes the real width and height of the content and sizes the element accordingly. `float: right;` does quite same thing but.. it floats to the right. `clear: both;` is put to the element so that it says to any floated elements to buzz off if theyre in its left or right. So `clear`is used to kind of undo what float does. That one `clear: none;` was maybe too confusing. but i set that because it was easier for me. Not having `clear: both;`in element does the same thing.

Comment: Heres without `clear: both;` http://jsfiddle.net/hdxdw/6/ Heres with `clear: both;` http://jsfiddle.net/hdxdw/5/ - Note that as you have set a height value to the element the height is what you have set it to. same applies to width `float: left;` respects those values that you put but if you dont have any it wraps the element around the content.

Comment: By the way, it might help you understand better/more if you check the No clear: both; example ` (../hdxdw/6) by widening and shortening the width of the preview area. float: left; is not set in stone, if browser width is too low it will basically do same as clear: both; does always. ( but will of course wrap around the element still. )

Comment: `clear: both;` does not effect surrounding elements. It effects the element with the CSS declaration. Other elements will not "buzz off", it's the element that will "buzz". If there are no floating elements nearby, nothing will happen.

Comment: Its easier to think about it that way in my opinin.